# Efficiently find neighbors in python

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, cpython, nearest-neighbor

I have a three-dimensional grid. For each point on the grid, I want to find its nearest neighbours. Since my grid is uniformly sampled, I just want to gather the immediate neighbors.

**Sample grid:**

[image]

**Required neighbors:**

For a given point X, I need the following neighbors:

[image]

**My Current Working Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cProfile

class Neighbours:
    # Get neighbors
    @classmethod
    def get_neighbour_indices(cls, row, col, frame, distance=1):                
        # Define the indices for the neighbor pixels    
        r = np.linspace(row - distance, row + distance, 2 * distance + 1)
        c = np.linspace(col - distance, col + distance, 2 * distance + 1)
        f = np.linspace(frame - distance, frame + distance, 2 * distance + 1)
        nc, nr, nf = np.meshgrid(c, r, f)
        neighbors = np.vstack((nr.flatten(), nc.flatten(), nf.flatten())).T
    
        # Filter out valid neighbor indices within the array bounds
        valid_indices = (neighbors[ :, 0] >= 0) & (neighbors[ :, 0] < nRows) & (neighbors[ :, 1] >= 0) & (neighbors[ :, 1] < nCols) & (neighbors[ :, 2] >= 0) & (neighbors[ :, 2] < nFrames) 

        # Return the valid neighbor indices
        valid_neighbors = neighbors[valid_indices]
        return valid_neighbors

    @classmethod
    def MapIndexVsNeighbours(cls):
        neighbours_info = np.empty((nRows * nCols * nFrames), dtype=object)
        for frame in range(nFrames):
            for row in range(nRows):
                for col in range(nCols):        
                    neighbour_indices = cls.get_neighbour_indices(row, col, frame, distance=1)        
                    flat_idx = frame * (nRows * nCols) + (row * nCols + col)
                    neighbours_info[flat_idx] = neighbour_indices                            

        return neighbours_info


########################------------------main()-------##################
####--run
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    nRows = 151
    nCols = 151
    nFrames = 24
    cProfile.run('Neighbours.MapIndexVsNeighbours()', sort='cumulative')  
    print()
```

**Problem:** For larger grids (e.g. 201 x 201 x 24), the program takes very long time. In the profiling results using `cProfile`, I can see that `meshgrid()` in the `get_neighbour_indices()` takes quite long. All in all, this is not an efficient implementation. Furthermore, I tried to execute the `MapIndexVsNeighbours()` on a separate thread but due to GIL lock, it does not really execute in parallel. So, something that can be execute in parallel would be a desired implementation.

Comment: The main issue is that you use Numpy for a use-case in which is is not intended to be fast : computing a huge amount of tiny arrays. Creating a Numpy array from the CPython interpreter is particularly slow : for example, each of the 3 `np.linspace` takes 13 µs on my i5-9600 CPU. This is 1000 times slower than what a code written in C/C++ do (in fact, a static array is even 10_000 times faster to create and fill than the Numpy code).

Comment: There are JIT like **Numba** that can make that certainly an order of magnitude faster (if not 2) but you need first to avoid creating such array in a loop of 201x201x24 ~= 1_000_000 iterations. While a Numba code can make it faster, a code with basic plain loops operating on data on the fly (i.e. avoiding creating a lot of temporary arrays) should be not so far from a native code. Note OOP is experimental in Numba and calling an member function a million time is certainly not very fast too. Cython might also be a good alternative.

Comment: Last but not least, Numpy arrays with the type `dtype=object` are basically not better than list performance-wise. In fact, CPython lists are certainly faster (while they are actually pretty slow). Numpy support CPython dynamic objects only for convenience, not performance. If you care about performance, you should really avoid them.

Comment: Maybe all you need is pre-allocate WxHxDx24 array and write original array into it 24 times (with some extra code and nuances to deal with boundaries)?

Comment: do you want a [sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)?

Comment: @Nin17: Looks interesting! If the spacing of cells is irregular, this can provide neighbours within a given radius?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by irregular spacing of cells. Sliding window view provides every valid window of the given shape along the given axes around each point in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can speed-up the computation for example with [numba](/questions/tagged/numba):

```py
from timeit import timeit

from numba import njit


@njit
def get_arr(x, y, f, w, h, distance, frames):
    _x_from = max(0, x - distance)
    _x_to = min(w - 1, x + distance)

    _y_from = max(0, y - distance)
    _y_to = min(h - 1, y + distance)

    _z_from = max(0, f - distance)
    _z_to = min(frames - 1, f + distance)

    shape = ((_x_to + 1) - _x_from) * ((_y_to + 1) - _y_from) * ((_z_to + 1) - _z_from)
    out = np.empty(shape=(shape, 3), dtype=np.int32)

    i = 0
    for _x in range(_x_from, _x_to + 1):
        for _y in range(_y_from, _y_to + 1):
            for _z in range(_z_from, _z_to + 1):
                out[i, 0] = _x
                out[i, 1] = _y
                out[i, 2] = _z
                i += 1
    return out


def MapIndexVsNeighbours_numba(nRows, nCols, nFrames):
    neighbours_info = np.empty((nRows * nCols * nFrames), dtype=object)
    for frame in range(nFrames):
        for row in range(nRows):
            for col in range(nCols):
                neighbour_indices = get_arr(row, col, frame, nRows, nCols, 1, nFrames)
                flat_idx = frame * (nRows * nCols) + (row * nCols + col)
                neighbours_info[flat_idx] = neighbour_indices
    return neighbours_info


nRows = 151
nCols = 151
nFrames = 24

v1 = MapIndexVsNeighbours_numba(nRows, nCols, nFrames)
v2 = Neighbours.MapIndexVsNeighbours()
assert all(np.allclose(a, b) for a, b in zip(v1, v2))

t_numba = timeit(
    "MapIndexVsNeighbours_numba(nRows, nCols, nFrames)", number=1, globals=globals()
)
t_original = timeit("Neighbours.MapIndexVsNeighbours()", number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"{t_numba=}")
print(f"{t_original=}")
```

Prints on my machine AMD 5700x:

```
t_numba=0.46780765103176236
t_original=31.86005672905594
```

---

- With `201 x 201 x 24` the numba function took `1.1439994741231203`
- With `1024 x 1024 x 24` the numba function took `22.353679422987625`

Comment: Good try! I think it should be faster to create the output array of `get_arr` with a predefined size and then fill it rather than creating an array from the list. One can also write a specialised function for the case `distance=1` assuming it is a common case (or possibly the most frequent ones).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, preallocating the `out` array significantly speeds up the computation (~22s vs ~62s with 1024x1024x24). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it has indeed increased the performance. Still waiting if someone has any other proposal. Upvoted meanwhile :)