# Numba Exception: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>

Tags: python, numba

I want to convert a function to Numba for performance reasons. My **MWE** example is below. If I remove the `@njit` decorator then, the code works but with `@njit`, I am getting a runtime exception. The exception is most likely coming  because of the `dtype=object` to define the `result_arr` but I tried using `dtype=float64` also, but I get similar exception.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from timeit import timeit

######-----------Required NUMBA function----------###
#@njit #<----without this, the code works
def required_numba_function():
    nRows = 151
    nCols = 151
    nFrames = 24
    result_arr = np.empty((151* 151 * 24), dtype=object)

    for frame in range(nFrames):
        for row in range(nRows):
            for col in range(nCols):        
                size_rows = np.random.randint(8, 15) 
                size_cols = np.random.randint(2, 6)            
                args = np.random.normal(3, 2.5, size=(size_rows, size_cols)) # size is random
                flat_idx = frame * (nRows * nCols) + (row * nCols + col)
                result_arr[flat_idx] = args

    return result_arr

######------------------main()-------##################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    required_numba_function()

    print()
```

How can I resolve the Numba exception?

Comment: You cannot have CPython objects in `@njit` functions. Types are what make Numba fast. Without them `njit`ting is not possible (only `@jit` which is rather useless IMHO). Hence my comments in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789489/efficiently-find-neighbors-in-python).

Comment: `result_arr[flat_idx]` is a scalar while `args` is an array. This is why you get another error with `dtype=np.float64`. The array needs not to be 1D or you should assign slices. There is no other option.

Comment: The code doesn't work without the `njit` decorator (with `dtype=np.float64`), I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` numpy version 1.26.2

Comment: @Nin17: Strange, for me it is working by commenting out the `@njit`. To cross-verify, I copy-pasted the code from here and ran it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify, if you change the dtype to `float64` from `object` it no longer works without the decorator. With `dtype=object` it works but is not supported by numba.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: I need the `result_arr` to be an array of arrays, because then in my full code, I can get the results for a particular index easily.

Comment: @Nin17: yes, that's correct. I am wondering if I can specify something as `dtype` to make it work but as  @Jérôme Richard mentioned above, it might not be the case.

Comment: why can't the result just be a single array rather than an array of arrays?

Comment: @Nin17: Because in my actual code, the number of elements in the `args` are not same. The number of elements in the `args` will change. So, if the `result_arr` is just a single large flat array, I would not be able to find the values present in a particular `args`. In the current code, if I need to know the values for `index = 2`, I can simply access `result_arr[2]`.

Comment: @Nin17: Code updated to make it clear why can't I have a predefined flat array to store results `result_arr`.

Comment: Can you have a list of arrays instead? This is compatible with numba and ~3x faster for me.

Comment: @Nin17: Yes, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say that a list of arrays is fine, you can just replace the assignment of `result_array` with an empty array of `dtype=object` with an empty list that you append to at each iteration - this is compatible with numba:

```
@nb.njit
def required_numba_function2():
    np.random.seed(0) # Just for testing, you seem to have to set the seed within the function for numba to be aware of it
    nRows = 151
    nCols = 151
    nFrames = 24
    result_arr = []

    for frame in range(nFrames):
        for row in range(nRows):
            for col in range(nCols):        
                size_rows = np.random.randint(8, 15) 
                size_cols = np.random.randint(2, 6)            
                args = np.random.normal(3, 2.5, size=(size_rows, size_cols)) # size is random
                result_arr.append(args)

    return result_arr
```

Test

```
np.random.seed(0)
result = required_numba_function()
result2 = required_numba_function2()
for i, j in zip(result, result2):
    assert np.allclose(i, j)
```

Time:

```
%timeit required_numba_function()
%timeit required_numba_function2()
```

```
2.08 s ± 37.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
606 ms ± 3.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```